# Ruby: running external processes in parallel and keeping track of exit codes

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I have a smoke test that I run against my servers before making them live.  At the moment it runs in serial form and takes around 60s per server.  I can run these in parallel and I've done it with `Thread.new` which is great as it runs them a lot faster but I lose track of whether the test actually passed or not.

I'm trying to improve this by using `Process.spawn` to manage my processes.

```
pids = []
uris.each do |uri|
    command = get_http_tests_command("Smoke")
    update_http_tests_config( uri )
    pid = Process.spawn( system( command ) )
    pids.push pid
    Process.detach pid
end

# make sure all pids return a passing status code
# results = Process.waitall
```

I'd like to kick off all my tests but then afterwards make sure that all the tests return a passing status code.

I tried using `Process.waitall` but I believe that to be incorrect and used for forks, not spawns.

After all the process have completed I'd like to return the status of true if they all pas or false if any one of them fails.

[Documentation here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Process.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
statuses = pids.map { |pid| Process.wait(pid, 0); $? }
```

This waits for each of the process ids to finish, and checks for the result status set in `$?` for each process

Comment: And this is why I love ruby :D